# tor browser loading but Nothing to see on ubuntu 20.04 ... please help

Tags: 20.04, tor, tor-browser

I can run tor services for my other apps (telegram for example but the tor browser app doesn't work and I don't know what to do ...I have tried to use the tor launcher app but nothing ... my system is updated and downloaded the last version of tor browser on the tor project website
clicking on the .desktop app (the previous version of tor browser has .deb instead...however...) but loading but nothing appears...

Comment: Hey apm! [Right click on `start-tor-browser.desktop`, open Properties or Preferences and change the permission to allow executing file as program.](https://tb-manual.torproject.org/installation/) Now try to open the `.desktop` file. Is it working? BTW, I suggest you to go through the [tour] page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open Files (GNOME Files/Nautilus).
2. Click on the hamburger button and click on *Preferences*.
3. Go to the *Behavior* tab and under *Executable Text Files* select *Run them* or *Ask what to do*. If you choose the latter click on *Run* after launching the `start-tor-browser.desktop` file.